# Does the number of geth's maxpeers option include it's own node?

Tags: go-ethereum

In `geth`'s parameters there is a `--maxpeers` option. Does this option number includes it's own node?

> `--maxpeers "25"` Maximum number of network peers (network disabled if set to 0)

Does `--maxpeers "1"` means 2 peers in the network including the node which execute the `geth` command with `--maxpeers "1"`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Does the number of maxpeers of geth option include it's own node?**

No. Specifying the parameter:

- `--maxpeers 0` will not allow your `geth` instance to connect to any other peer
- `--maxpeers 1` will allow your `geth` instance to connect to one other peer
- `--maxpeers n` will allow your `geth` instance to connect to *n* other nodes

**Does --maxpeers "1" means 2 peers in the network including the node which executed the geth command with --maxpeers "1"?**

No. Your `geth` instance where you specified `--maxpeers 1` will have at maximum 1 connection to another peer instance. However the other peer instance may have connections to many another instances.

Details below.

---

**Test Environment**

- Single computer with 5 `geth` instances running on ports 30301, 30302, 30303, 30304 and 30305 .
- All instances have the same `--networkid 8888` and `--genesis CustomGenesis.json` files - a private network.
- All instances have a different `--datadir {directory}` parameter.
- `geth` instances 2, 3, 4 and 5 all have their enode URL information listed in `static-nodes.json` in the `--datadir {directory}`.
- IF `geth` instance 1 is also listed in the `static-nodes.json` and a copy of this file is also available in it's `--datadir {directory}`, all 4 other `geth` instances will be connected to it as peers, regardless of the number specified in each of the `geth` instance's `--maxpeer` parameter.
- IF `geth` instance 1 does not have the `static-nodes.json` file but instead uses the `--bootnodes {enode URL}` and the `--maxpeers {n}` parameters, the number of connections that `geth` instance 1 will be connected to is *n* separate `geth` nodes.
- IF `geth` instance 1 does not have the `static-nodes.json` file but instead uses the `--bootnodes {enode URL}` and the `--maxpeers {n}` followed by the `--nodiscover` parameter, `geth` instance 1 will connect to *n* separate `geth` nodes. `--nodiscover` does not run `geth` in stand-alone mode.

Answer (score 6):

`--maxpeers "1"` means one peer computer is connected to your node.

if you run `> admin.peers` in geth console it will return `[]` if you are running in `--dev` mode

### to see connected peers

```
> admin.peers
```

returns

```
{
    caps: ["eth/61", "eth/62", "eth/63"],
    id: "dcae857cb89ab8xxxxxx32bde07ecff2b836bef51cba90a157afe05df50636a7",
    name: "Geth/v1.3.5/linux/go1.5.1",
    network: {
      localAddress: "37.139.x.xx:30303",
      remoteAddress: "46.x.xxx.162:33208"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 13215741744858590000,
        head: "1e3da5c7aea3c9300c57622532ce6a00edb79fdc6b05e79f9e4bc5930c1cf46c",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}
```

#### To see no of peers connected

```
> admin.peers.length
```

returns

> 13 // means 13 nodes connected to your node.