# How many peers can an Ethereum node have?

Tags: nodes, peers

Is there any maximum limit on the number of peers an Ethereum node can have? Does this vary for private and public networks?

In case of Bitcoin, is there a limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an ethereum geth node you can specify the maximum number of peer with help of the `--maxpeers` command-line flag (see https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options). It defaults to 25.
This limits depends on the node type (e.g. parity or ccp-ethereum have different defaults)

See also

- [Ethereum selection of peer nodes and centralization](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19331/ethereum-selection-of-peer-nodes-and-centralization)
- https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/9007/how-many-peers-does-one-node-have
- [Does the number of geth's maxpeers option include it's own node?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/does-the-number-of-geths-maxpeers-option-include-its-own-node)

With regard to bitcoin I found this stackexchange entry that states that the limit is 125 (8 outbound+117 inbound) see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/44504/is-there-a-connections-limit-on-bitcoind